# DirectX функция D3DXVec3Normalize, нормализация вектора

Tags: c++, directx

Начал изучать графику, изучаю функции мат. библиотеки dx, и одна функция отказывается работать. Код:

```
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <D3DX10math.h>
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine,  
int nCmdShow) 
{
    D3DVECTOR vect;
    vect.x = 45;
    vect.y = 75;
    vect.z = -9;

    D3DXVECTOR3 new_vector(vect);
    D3DXVECTOR3 new_vector1(45.6, 83.4, 93.245);
    D3DXVECTOR3 result = new_vector + new_vector1;
    D3DXVECTOR3 new_vector2(1, 2, 3);

    float _module = D3DXVec3Length(&new_vector2); // sqrt(1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2) 
    D3DXVECTOR3 normvect;
    //D3DXVec3Normalize(&normvect, &new_vector2);  // не работает

    return 0;
}
```

Ошибки следующего рода:
Неразрешённый символ и т.д.

Как подлечить?

Comment: Может все же приведете текст ошибки? Вам же явно компилятор/IDE выдала что-то более внятное, чем "Неразрешённый символ".

Comment: @Flowneee не привёл поэтому:
LNK2019 ёё√ыър эр эхЁрчЁх°хээ√щ тэх°эшщ ёшьтюы _D3DXVec3Normalize@8 т ЇєэъЎшш _WinMain@16 test_dx_path Z:\programming\directX\test_dx_path\main_dx.obj 1

И вот эта: LNK1120 эхЁрчЁх°хээ√ї тэх°эшї ¤ыхьхэЄют: 1 test_dx_path Z:\programming\directX\test_dx_path\Debug\test_dx_path.exe 1

Comment: Добился более-менее этого сообщения:
Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _D3DXVec3Normalize@8 в функции _WinMain@16 test_dx_path Z:\programming\directX\test_dx_path\main_dx.obj 1 


Ошибка LNK1120 неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1 test_dx_path Z:\programming\directX\test_dx_path\Debug\test_dx_path.exe 1

Comment: На месте..каталоги библиотек прописаны, файл в наличии в каталоге.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решила автоматическая линковка d3dx9.lib

```
#pragma comment (lib,"D3dx9.lib")
```